# Support Vector Machine distance from hyperplane and certainty

Tags: machine-learning, libsvm, svm

Does a vector's distance from the decision plane in a support vector machine (with arbitrary configuration with regards to kernel, etc.) correlate in any way to the machine's confidence/certainty of that vector's classification?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  This is why Platt Scaling, which monotonically transforms the margin can produce calibrated probabilities, for example.

However, without transforming the margin, it's hard to give a workable interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I would most certainly say it does. Some formalization given here: http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes3.pdf